# How to correctly write units (second, Hertz) in formulae?

Tags: support, editing, formatting, markdown

I cannot recommend enough the package [`siunitx`](ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/macros/latex/exptl/siunitx/siunitx.pdf) in `latex` for unit  and number formatting. What is the  method of choice to write and to correct abbreviated units in SE.DSP posts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tend to use `\mathrm{}` macro with a tiny space:

```
\;\mathrm{Hz}
```

Another possibility is to use simple `\text{}` mode instead.

Comment: And what about  microhertz? $\;\mathrm{\mu Hz}$?

Comment: Yes, that's what I usually do :)